# Trying to understand waf options

Tags: samba, waf

I'm a noob to waf. I need to configure, build & install samba-4.1.4 on my RHL 6.5 system.
Trying to understand waf options specifically I've noted a lot of "with-xxxxx" options, and a few 
"without-xxxxx" options. My question is: can I specify "without-xxxxx" if I don't want a particular samba feature built?  e.g. there's a default "with-ldap", can I specify "without-ldap" ?? 
The supplied documentation does not specify exactly how to negate a default option. 
I hope I've made myself clear
Thanks

Guy

Comment: Usually, if there's a -withxxx, that feature isn't enabled by default.

Comment: Yes, thanks I went ahead and used the without-xxxx and ran the waf config process and it ran w/o error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks I went ahead and used the without-xxxx and ran the waf config process and it ran w/o error